# Error while a pointer it's used inside a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, char, void

I have a void function that works very well until I try to use it to show a string.

```
void Frandom(int tam, char* itens[]){

    int pote[tam];

    srand((time(NULL)));

    for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++){
        int achou;
        do{
            pote[i] = rand() % tam;
            achou = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){

            if(pote[i] == pote[j]){
                achou = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        }while(achou);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++){
        printf("Tema %d >>> %s\n", pote[i], itens[i]); // I think that here is the problem
    }
}
```

The compiler says to expect char**, but `itens[]` is char*. I've tried to change but doesn't works.

Another thing: Calling the function.

```
Frandom(qtd_temas, tnome[qtd_temas]); //works

Frandom(qtd_temas, tnome[]); //doesn't works
```

Comment: How is `tnome` declared in the caller?

Comment: Also, the algorithm being used to shuffle an array of integers is extremely inefficient.  It should be O(n), but what you have is O(n*\*3) average (and theoretically unbounded).

Comment: @Tom Karzes ''char* tnome[qtd_temas];'' To be more specific: I've used malloc to set itens' size (dynamic allocation), then I have a pointer that allocates memory spaces for each string I will receive. As if it were: iten [any number] = {"string", "string", "string"}.

Answer (score 1):

use  `void Frandom(int tam, char itens[])` instead of `void Frandom(int tam, char *itens[])` also use `printf("Tema %d >>> %c\n", pote[i], itens[i]);`

Comment: It's supposed to be an array of strings, i.e. an array of `char *`, not an array of `char`.  So this answer won't work.

Comment: `printf("Tema %d >>> %s\n", pote[i], itens[i])` here he should use %c instead of %s then everything will work fine if he uses my solution

Comment: That's one interpretation of the problem, but I don't think it's the correct one.  I don't think OP wants to shuffle an array of characters.  I think OP wants to shuffle an array of strings.  So I believe this answer is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, but it also doesn't works. To be more specific: I've used malloc to set itens' size (dynamic allocation), then I have a pointer that allocates memory spaces for each string I will receive. As if it were: iten [any number] = {"string", "string", "string"}.